# Prediction Model with Small Sample Size

Tags: predictive-models, prediction, small-sample, unbalanced-classes

I am interested in running a prediction model to determine which of 7 continuous IVs best contribute to my dichotomous DV. Each of these are univariately significantly associate with my outcome variable.

My problem is that my sample size is small and unbalanced: for the (0) outcome there are 15 observations and for the (1) outcome there are 60 observations.

I believe the rule of thumb is to have at least 10 observations of each outcome for each possible predictor variable.

What should I do? Is there any other analytical approach that will work reliably in determining which IVs explain the DV the best and also I am interested in the % variance of each of these in contribution to the DV.

Thank you to all for any suggestions!

Comment: No.  Either just go with simple models or else gt more data. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you. By simple models do you mean just univariate?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant.